# gazebo garden simulating plane with camera

Tags: gazebo, camera

i am trying to simulate a plane with camera in gz garden
i want to see resolution and foV settings
is it possible doing this in garden do i need to use ROS
or should i just switch to classic
it would be so much of help if you can answer

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify if you mean "airplane" or "ground plane". If the answer is ground plane, there are many tutorials on how to set up a simulated camera in gazebo-ignition, so do a web search for them.